# Format month name to local language

Tags: php, translate

I made a booking system and now I've a problem with month name. In this case, it's in English and I want to be in Portuguese.

I tried to use `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR')` and `strftime` in the `mktime` statement.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR');
    
     // Create array containing abbreviations of days of week.
     $daysOfWeek = array('Domingo','Segunda','Terça','Quarta','Quinta','Sexta','Sábado');

     // What is the first day of the month in question?
     $firstDayOfMonth = mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year);

     // How many days does this month contain?
     $numberDays = date('t',$firstDayOfMonth);

     // Retrieve some information about the first day of the
     // month in question.
     $dateComponents = getdate($firstDayOfMonth);

     // What is the name of the month in question?
     $monthName = $dateComponents['month'];

     // What is the index value (0-6) of the first day of the
     // month in question.
     $dayOfWeek = $dateComponents['wday'];

     // Create the table tag opener and day headers
     
    $datetoday = date('Y-m-d');
    
    
    
    $calendar = "<table class='table table-bordered'>";
    $calendar .= "<center><h2>$monthName $year</h2>";
    $calendar.= "<a class='btn btn-xs btn-primary' href='?month=".date('m', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month-1, 1, $year))."&year=".date('Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month-1, 1, $year))."'>Mês Anterior</a> ";
    
    $calendar.= " <a class='btn btn-xs btn-primary' href='?month=".date('m')."&year=".date('Y')."'>Atual Mês</a> ";
    
    $calendar.= "<a class='btn btn-xs btn-primary' href='?month=".date('m', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month+1, 1, $year))."&year=".date('Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month+1, 1, $year))."'>Próximo Mês</a></center><br>";
```

As you can see in `$dayOfWeek` it has the day name from Sunday to Saturday and in the buttons the text contains Previous Month, Current Month and Next Month, respectively.

Could anyone help me where to insert `strftime` to translate the month name, please? I tried in every place and I always get an error or the calendar stops working.

**UPDATE**:
So, I added some lines in the code and I'm still not able to translate the month name

```
// What is the name of the month in question?
$monthName = $dateComponents['month'];

setlocale(LC_TIME, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese');
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
echo strftime('%B %Y', strtotime($monthName));
```

All I get is March instead of Março.

I made it work but some special characters like ç aren't working:

```
mar�o 2021
```

**SOLUTION**:
utf8_encode solved the problem

```
// What is the name of the month in question?
$monthName = $dateComponents['month'];

setlocale(LC_TIME, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese');
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
echo utf8_encode(strftime('%B %Y', strtotime($monthName)));
```

Comment: what error do you get ? and what do you mean by "the calendar stops working" ? do you get an error ? a blank page ? or an unexpected result ?

Comment: I'm sorry for being away for so long, I'll edit the question with what I did and the result I get.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not use `\LC_ALL` without a specific reason to do that, since you only want to change the `\LC_TIME`. Therefore you should use `\setlocale(\LC_TIME, 'pt_BR');`.

Do also not forget to set your default timezone:

```
\date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
```

You also say, that you would always get an error. In order to help you, we need the error message.

Comment: I was able to solve the error but I'm still not getting the translation. I'm sorry being away for so long